# jtree transferhandler, data not inserted correctly

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, jtree

i try to drag a component to a jtree.

that don't work for some case example:

root

A it's a leaf
B it's child of A

if i try to insert it like a child of B, it will be inserted like a child of the root
public class TreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

```
JTree tree;
DataFlavor nodesFlavor;
DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodesToRemove;
String mimeType = DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + ";class=" + CommandBeans.class.getName();
DataFlavor dataFlavor = new DataFlavor(mimeType, "command");

public TreeTransferHandler(JTree tree) {
    this.tree = tree;
}

public TreeTransferHandler() {
}

@Override
public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {

    if (!info.isDataFlavorSupported(dataFlavor)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
    //Nous n'autorisons donc que la copie ici
    return COPY;
}

@Override
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {

    if (!canImport(support)) {
        return false;
    }

    
    JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
    
    TreePath path = dl.getPath();
    int index = dl.getChildIndex();
    CommandBeans command = null;
    
    Transferable data = support.getTransferable();
    try {
        command = (CommandBeans) data.getTransferData(dataFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TreeTransferHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TreeTransferHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(command.getName());
    
    DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) this.tree.getModel();
    index = (index == -1) ? model.getChildCount(path.getLastPathComponent()) : index;
    model.insertNodeInto(newNode, parentNode, index);

    tree.makeVisible(path.pathByAddingChild(newNode));
    tree.scrollPathToVisible(path);

    return true;
}
}
```

it's like drop location and insertion it's not good.

it's seem to have a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6560955#

Any suggestion?